# Consolidate rows based on match conditions 3 columns and join data from 4th column delineated by semicolon

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro in excel that merges rows with duplicate data in columns A, B and D into a single row that showing that data while also pulling in the data from column e from each of those and delineates by a semicolon.

Group Product description, Sign Type, Quantity -> join Distribution in semicolon delimited string

As an example I have the below
3 rows right now that read as follows

| Column A(product description) | Column B (Sign Type) | Column D(Quantity) | Column E(Distro) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New Product | 4" Rail | 1 | TV |
| New Product | 4" Rail | 1 | Ontario |
| New Product | 4" Rail | 1 | Riggins |

I want the macro to run and consolidate them so instead of 3 lines I have 1 and it reads

| Column A(product description) | Column B (Sign Type) | Column D(Quantity) | Column E(Distro) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New Product | 4" Rail | 1 | TV; Ontario; Riggins |

I would want it to run through the whole sheet and consolidate like that. I can't seem to find any VBA code that would work. I started with this. But it just errors. Any help SUPER appreciated!

```
Sub CreateDistributionReport()
' TODO: Group Product description, Sign Type, Quantity -> join Distribution in semicolon deliminated string

' find product description, sign type, quantity
' while unchanged
With Sheets("Output")
Dim groupedProductDescription As Long
groupedProductDescription = .Rows(1).Find(what:="A Shoc 16 OZ B1G1 for a $1").Column

Rows(groupedProductDescription).Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Would probably be easier and faster to use power query. [Here is a Guide](https://exceloffthegrid.com/power-query-combine-rows-into-a-single-cell/)

Comment: So you're looking to keep interacting with the sheet... you will need [`find` and `findnext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext), most likely.  It may behoove you to use `Match()` to determine if you have more than one, or capture everything into an array and do the work all within VBA.  There are lots of options, and I would suggest doing a bit of research to determine your path forward, as this is not a code-for-you service.  Once you've updated your post with some more depth, we can work further.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateDistributionReport()
' TODO: Group Product description, Sign Type, Quantity -> join Distribution in semicolon deliminated string

' find product description, sign type, quantity
' while unchanged

'OBS!: Assuming columns are sorted

    Dim rStart As Range: Set rStart = Range("A2")
    Dim data, cell As Range
        
    Set data = Range(rStart, rStart.End(xlDown))
    
    For i = data.Rows.Count + 1 To 1 Step -1
        
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = a And Cells(i, 2).Value = b And Cells(i, 4).Value = d Then
            Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 5).Text + ";" + e
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Select
            Cells(i, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
            a = Cells(i, 1).Value
            b = Cells(i, 2).Value
            d = Cells(i, 4).Value
            e = Cells(i, 5).Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Cheers!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-macro solution, this seems pretty easy to solve with excel formulas.  I am using the smart table feature in excel to make the table easier to work with.

[image]

Column Formulas:

- E: `=CONCAT([@[Column A]],[@[Column B]],[@[Column C]])` (easier to find matches against a single column)
- F: `=COUNTIF([Helper], [@Helper])`  (not really needed just curious how many matches per row, and you could sort highest to lowest to see)
- G: `=TEXTJOIN("; ", TRUE, IF([Helper]=[@Helper],[Column D]))`

Using textjoin() you can concatenate an infinite number of matches into a single string separated by your choice of delimeter.  I added a space after the semicolon but you could remove that if you don't like it.

- Then copy Column G and paste as values into a new column, or overwrite column D.
- Then you can highlight the data and click remove duplicates.

[image]

- The helper columns are find to keep unless you just don't want them.

[image]